# wsl2 DISPLAY variable on windows host

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver, wsl-2

I use windows 10 and WSL2.
To run linux applications on the X server hosted by the windows machine, I use the second command:
export WSL_HOST_IP=$( cmd.exe /C netsh interface ip show addresses "vEthernet (WSL)" | grep "IP Address" | sed -e "s/\s*IP Address:\s*//g" ) and it works:

echo $WSL_HOST_IP
172.20.48.1

how do i transform it into the DISPLAY variable?
what I want to get is this: DISPLAY = $WSL_HOST_IP:0.0 but I can't write ": 0.0" in bash. Anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: DISPLAY="$WSL_HOST_IP:0.0"?

Comment: echo $DISPLAY
:0.020.48.1

Comment: It looks like some substitution is taking place but I cannot recreate on my local WSL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove DOS line ending with `s/\r//`:

```
export WSL_HOST_IP=$( cmd.exe /C netsh interface ip show addresses "vEthernet (WSL)" | grep "IP Address" | sed -e "s/\sIP Address:\s//g; s/\r//" )
```